# React-router , router not workingg

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm newbie in reactjs, I tried build something with it but I had problem with react-router-redux. I get `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.` in console. Here is my code :

App.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
           {this.props.children}
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import App from './components/App';
import Login from './components/login/Login';
import Register from './components/register/Register';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Login}/>
    <Route path="register" component={Register}/>
  </Route>
);
```

And Index.js

```
...
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import routes from './routes';

const store = configureStore();
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes}>
     </Router>
    </Provider>,
     document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Where is my wrong? Please explain for me why I get this error. Thank in advance

Comment: What version of React Router are you using?

Comment: @Tholle `"react-router": "^4.3.1"` and `"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8"`

Comment: Alright. Your `Routes` component looks like it was written for React Router v3, and  the `Router` component in `Index.js` doesn't take a `routes` prop, but children instead: `<Router history={history}><Routes /></Router>`. Your own React components needs to have a capitalized first letter, `Routes` not `routes`.

Comment: @Tholle now I get error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object`. I think I had problem in export routes

Comment: Yes, you want the default export in `Routes` to be a function as well. `export default () => ( ... )`

Answer (score 2):

[React-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) is no longer maintained and support only 3.x and 2.x React-router versions

Repo authors suggest using [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) for React-rotuer 4.x bindings

Answer (score 2):

There are different routers for different environments, you want to use `BrowserRouter` instead of `Router`.

See [React Training BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) for more information.

**index.js**

```
// change this line
import { Router } from 'react-router';
// to
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
```

**NOTE:** You might also have to pass in your routes in a different way. This is shown in the **React Training** page provided above.